# Minimum no of changes required to make array strictly increasing

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a problem in which we have an array of positive numbers and we have to make it strictly increasing by making zero or more changes to the array elements.

We are asked the minimum number of changes required to make the array strictly increasing.

**Example**

if array is 1 2 9 10 3 15

so ans=1 if change 3 to some number between 12 to 14.

if 1 2 2 2 3 4 5

ans=5

since changing 2 to 3 then 2 to 4 then 3 to 5 then 4 to 6 then 5 to 7

**Constraints:**

Number of elements in array <= 10^6

Each element <= 10^9

Can somebody give me an algorithm?

Link to the detailed problem with sample test cases
https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/find-path/

Since it is mini/max problem, it sounds like dynamic programming to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Homework or not, you should still show an attempt at solving the problem. The constraints given makes it sound a lot like a programming contest.

Comment: I assume there's some constraint about non-negative / positive numbers as well, otherwise, for the second example, you can just change 1 to -1 and (1st) 2 to 0 and (2nd) 2 to 1.

Comment: No dynamic required !

Comment: Do you have to actually identify the required changes, or simply the number of changes that would need to be made? If the latter case, I think scanning the list once and noticing how many elements currently do not meet the criteria, and a little extra tracking of intervals to notice when changing one element would break neighboring elements that might not be broken yet would be the way to go...

Answer (score 13):

### HINT 1

This is very close to the standard [longest increasing subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) which is solvable in O(nlogn).

If you could change the numbers to decimals then the answer would be identical.
(Min number of changes = length of string-length of longest increasing subsequence)

However, as you need distinct integral values in between you will have to slightly modify the standard algorithm.

### HINT 2

Consider what happens if you change the array by doing x[i]=x[i]-i.

You now need to modify this changed array by making the smallest number of changes such that each element increases, or stays the same.

You can now search for the longest non-decreasing subsequence in this array and this will tell you how many elements can stay the same.

However, this may still use negative integers.

### HINT 3

One easy way to modify the algorithm to only use positive numbers is to append a whole lot of numbers at the start of the array.

i.e. change 1,2,9,10,3,15 to -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,9,10,3,15

Then you can be sure that the optimal answer will never decide to make the 1 go negative because it would cost so much to make all the negative numbers smaller.

(You can also modify the longest increasing subsequence algorithm to have the additional constraint, but this might be harder to code correctly in an interview situation.)

### EXAMPLE 1

Following this through on the initial example:

Original sequence

```
1,2,9,10,3,15
```

Add dummy elements at start

```
-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,9,10,3,15
```

Subtract off position in array

```
-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-4,-4,2,2,-6,5
```

Find longest non-decreasing sequence

```
-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-4,-4,2,2,*,5
```

So answer is to change one number.

### EXAMPLE 2

Original sequence

```
1,2,2,2,3,4,5
```

Add dummy elements at start

```
-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5
```

Subtract off position in array

```
-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-4,-4,-5,-6,-6,-6,-6
```

Find longest non-decreasing sequence

```
-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-4,-4,*,*,*,*,*
```

So answer is to change 5 numbers.

Comment: Can we do that without adding the dummy nodes and secondly say if the last no is 10^9 then we have to add 10^9 negetive dummy nodes,unneccesarily and that would increase our complexity. and in c/c++ we can't take that much memory.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz youre are wrong, you method is not working for example `50,51,50,50,52,53,57`, because you method always will change numbers for next positions, and will never go backward, since you are adding a increasing array at the start..

Comment: You only need to add a 10^6 dummy nodes (the same as the length of the sequence, not the maximum number).  You can also do it without adding the dummy nodes, but this would require a slight modification to the standard find longest increasing subsequence algorithm

Comment: @EugenHalca The method I am suggesting can decrease numbers, just not below 0.  The find longest non-decreasing subsequence is selecting the numbers which are unchanged.  The changed numbers can go up or down.

Answer (score 0):

**O(nlogn)** Running time

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Modify_The_Sequence {
        private static int n;
        private static int[] a;
        private static ArrayList<Integer> b;
        private static ArrayList<Integer> c;

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);

            n = d.nextInt();

            b = new ArrayList<>();
            c = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int x = d.nextInt();
                if (x - (i + 1) >= 0) {
                    b.add(x - (i + 1));
                }

            }

            /*
             * b.clear(); b.add(1); b.add(7); b.add(10); b.add(2); b.add(3);
             */
            // System.out.println(b);
            c.add(b.get(0));
            solve();
            System.out.println(n - c.size());
            // System.out.println(c);
        }

        private static void solve() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 1; i < b.size(); i++) {
                binaerysearch(0, c.size() - 1, i);
            }
        }

        private static void binaerysearch(int i, int j, int k) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int p = (i + j) / 2;
            if (i == j) {

                if (c.get(i) <= b.get(k)) {
                    if (i == c.size() - 1)
                        c.add(b.get(k));
                    else {

                        c.add(i + 1, b.get(k));
                        c.remove(i + 2);
                    }
                } else if (c.get(i) > b.get(k)) {
                    c.add(i, b.get(k));
                    c.remove(i + 1);

                }

            } else {
                if (c.get(p) > b.get(k)) {
                    if (p - 1 > i)
                        binaerysearch(i, p - 1, k);
                    else
                        binaerysearch(i, i, k);
                } else if (c.get(p) <= b.get(k)) {
                    if (p + 1 < j)
                        binaerysearch(p + 1, j, k);
                    else
                        binaerysearch(j, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Longest Increasing Sequence` to accommodate for squeezing integral values between two successive increasing elements can ensure that we have integral values at appropriate places.

Modified LIS code:

```
int convert(vector<int> v){
vector<int> lis(v.size(), 1);  
for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++){   
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){  
        if(v[i] > v[j] && lis[i] < lis[j]+1 && (i-j) <= (v[i]-v[j]))   
            lis[i] = lis[j]+1;  
    }  
}  
int max_lis = 0;  
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)  
    max_lis = max(max_lis, lis[i]);  
int ans = v.size() - max_lis;
return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inspired by the hits of @Peter de Rivaz,

I found the key condition of this problem is : num[i]-i >= num[j]-j >= 0 (i > j).

The following Java code (O(NlgN)) is the slight modification to the standard longest increasing subsequence algorithm, here we skip all the num[i] where num[i]-i < 0.

```
  static int resolve(int... nums) {
    int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
    dp[0] = nums[0];
    int right = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] >= i) {
        int realNum = nums[i] - i;
        if (realNum >= dp[right]) {
          right++;
          dp[right] = realNum;
        } else {
          dp[binarySearch(dp, 0, right, realNum)] = realNum;
        }
      }
    }
    return nums.length - (right + 1);
  }

  static int binarySearch(int[] nums, int left, int right, int key) {
    while (left <= right) {
      int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
      if (nums[mid] > key) {
        right = mid - 1;
      } else {
        left = mid + 1;
      }
    }
    return left;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

O(n) Running time:

```
def min_changes(li):
  change, check = 0, 0
  li_len = len(li)
  if li_len in [0,1]:
    return change
  else:
    check = li[0]
  for i in range(1, len(li)):
    if check >= li[i]:
      li[i] = check +1
      change += 1
      check += 1
    else:
      check = li[i]
  return change
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Answer (score -1):

Mine Solution with Time and Space Complexity
of O(n) and O(1) In python

```
arr = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5]
count = 0
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if(arr[i]>=arr[i+1]):
        arr[i+1] = arr[i]+1
        count += 1
print(count)
```