# Minimum changes required to make the array in increasing or decreasing order

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array where I want to find out the minimum number of values I need to make to change the array to be in increasing or decreasing order.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,5,6,5,7] 

In above array, a[4]=5 which is less than a[3]=6. So I can add 1 to 5 to make it 6 so array becomes a=[1,2,5,6,6,7]. It is ok if I have same values consecutively.
```

I have written below program but I am not sure if this works fine for all cases.

```
public int process(List<Integer> list) {

    int up = 0;
    int down = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        int left = list.get(i);
        int right = list.get(i + 1);
        if (left > right) {
            up += left - right;
        } else {
            down += right - left;
        }
    }
    if(up < down) {
       return up;
    } else {
       return down;
    }     
}
```

This is my interview question, and I was told that the program fails for some scenarios which I am not able to find out.

Comment: what return slope.get()?

Comment: Those are list elements, I updated my question

Comment: Well, if I give it the input 1,2,9,1,4,5,6, it gives me back 8, which seems wrong.

Comment: @Jeutnarg, that should be correct right. If my sequence in the end is 1,2,3,3,4,5,6. Means substracting 6 from 9 & adding 2 to 1 so total 6+2=8

Comment: That makes "minimum number of values I need to make to change" very unclear to me, then. I interpreted it as needing to know how many different items in the list had to change, not how much they needed to change.

Comment: For input `[2, 1, 3, 1]`, it gives `2` as output. I think the answer should be `3`. [Here](https://ideone.com/8P7VtI)

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is asking about your sorts, and how many iterations it would take for that sort to accomplish the goal of sorting your numbers, whether it is ascending or descending order. Were you allowed to use common sorts? If so, I would either make Selection sort or a Merge Sort program. I actually did that on a personal project and also had it count iterations to compare the speeds of different sorts. Merge Sort took me a while to reproduce, but Selection Sort is quite simple to do.

Each of these sorts have best and worst case scenarios.

**EDIT**

I also found this: 
[Minimum no of changes required to make array strictly increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048600/minimum-no-of-changes-required-to-make-array-strictly-increasing)

Comment: The link is about strictly increasing, in my case it can be increasing or decreasing and can be same value consecutiely.

Comment: there are multiple answers in that post, which answer you are referring to?

Comment: All of the answers are pretty decent, but I was thinking of using the first one. Now you said that you want to see the minimum value of changes... changes in what way? Are you assuming that you will just swap two numbers if they are out of order? Or will you put the out of place number immediately in place. What kind of sort are you using?

Comment: It is there in my question - `In above array, a[4]=5 which is less than a[3]=3. So I can add 1 to 5 to make it 6 so array becomes a=[1,2,5,6,6,7]. It is ok if I have same values consecutively.` It is bout adding numbers

Comment: No problem, I now understand what you're doing! Okay, nevermind the sorts then...